# AJAX-like non-blocking asynchronous Python requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

I looked through numerous questions and answers but none work for me.
Is there a way to achieve AJAX-like functionality in Python?

Let's say you have this setup:

```
url = "http://httpbin.org/delay/5"
print(requests.get(url))
foo()
```

As the `requests.get` blocks code execution, `foo()` won't trigger until you got a server response.

In Javascript, for example, the script continues working:

```
var requests = {
    get: function(url, callback) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                callback(this);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}

function response_goes_through_here(r) {
    console.log(r.responseText);

}

var url = "http://httpbin.org/delay/5"
requests.get(url, response_goes_through_here)
foo()
```

I tried `grequests`, but it still hangs until the whole queue is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Python 3, take a look at [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It allows you to make and handle asynchronous requests like:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('https://api.github.com/events') as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(await resp.text()
```

Comment: Does it block the thread though? Most of the examples I saw stop code execution until a response is received.